# How to skip over a line in a different function - Python?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this function:

```
def game_on():
''' I'm not a rat, Agent Kujan. '''
    def easter_egg():
        print('Easter Egg: Mmmm... Cadbury.')
    print("Kaizer Sozegg!")
    sys.exit()
    print('The greatest trick the Easter Bunny ever pulled...')
```

The main function:

```
def main():
    sandbox()
    game_on()
```

I have to use the sandbox() function to make the game_on() function not print "Kaizer Sozegg!" and then not exit, and once the sandbox function finishes, it needs to keep running the main function as normal. I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: `def sandbox(): sys.exit()`??

Comment: Then the main function doesn't go to the game_on at all...It still needs to print that last line

Comment: `sys.exit()` in `game_on()` will exit before the last line is printed.

Comment: I know. I need to skip over it without modifying the game_on() function, by using commands in the sandbox() function.

Comment: Why are you doing this, this will take some seriously breaking monkey patching...

Comment: If it wasn't the constraints of the problem, I wouldn't be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a terrible way of achieving what you are looking to do, despite me not knowing why you are trying to do it (only works in Python 3, or with `print_function` future):

```
def sandbox():
    global print
    def print_decorator(fn):
        def wraps(*args, **kwargs):
            if args[0] != "Kaizer Sozegg!":
                fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wraps
    print = print_decorator(print)

    def exit_patch(i=0):
        pass
    sys.exit = exit_patch
```